# Pass text input value to IBM Worklight adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

1. Will the below code  accept the values from client and pass to adapter?
2. Will my JS function validate if the username and password are present in db?

**HTML**

```
<form action="index.html" onsubmit="return(login())">
    UserName:<input type="text" name="uname" id="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="pass" id="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function login() {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'sq',
        procedure : "validateLogin",
        parameters : [$('#username').val(),$('#password').val()]
    };

    var options = {
        onSuccess : success,
        onFailure : failure
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}

function success() {
    var allNames = new String();
    var allpass = new String();

    for (var i = 0; i < response.invocationResult.resultSet.length; i++) {
        allNames+= response.invocationResult.resultSet[i].name;
        allpass+= response.invocationResult.resultSet[i].pass;
    }

    var a=new String();
    var b=new String();
    a=JSON.stringify(allNames);
    b=JSON.stringify(allpass);

    if (a==$('#username').val() && b==$('#password').val() ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function failure() {
    return false;
}
```

**Adapter procedure**

```
var query = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(
    "select name,pass from userreg where name=? and pass=?");

function validateLogin(username,password) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : query,
        parameters : [username,password]
    });
}
```

Comment: So, are you getting any error?

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq every time i click login button it is redirecting to index.html

Comment: Well duh, action="index.html"!?

Comment: So, what are you trying to do? You wants to redirect user to some other page after login?

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq yes.. after validating it should redirect

Comment: In form action write your page name, It may resolve your problem

Comment: It will be nice, if you validate your user on server side. i.e. After getting data from table in your validateLogin method, you should compare user credential with stored credential and return true or false based on whether user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<form id="frmId" onsubmit="return(login())">
    UserName:<input type="text" name="uname" id="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="pass" id="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Success Function :**

```
function success() {
    var allNames = new String();
    var allpass = new String();

    for (var i = 0; i < response.invocationResult.resultSet.length; i++) {
        allNames+= response.invocationResult.resultSet[i].name;
        allpass+= response.invocationResult.resultSet[i].pass;
    }

    var a=new String();
    var b=new String();
    a=JSON.stringify(allNames);
    b=JSON.stringify(allpass);

    if (a==$('#username').val() && b==$('#password').val() ){
        $("#frmId").attr('action', URL of the page you wants to redirect to);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ,@idan adar im using wl.logger.warn in my adapter to confirm the that parameter is passing to adapter but there is no parameter is displayed by warn

Comment: @user3510619 try to alert the value of your username and password in javascript before calling adapter

Comment: before calling adapter procedure im able to alert the name & password

Comment: Can you please share your project on drop box and give the link to me, so that I can look at it